# Installing mysql gem in home dir (no root access) install:wheel: invalid argument Error code 67

Tags: ruby, rubygems

so I'm trying to install gems in custom folders and as it is working with other gems I can't install mysql gem.

Googling didn't help
error code (not full) for better focus

```
make install
/usr/bin/install -c -o root -g wheel -m 0755 mysql_api.so /home/user/gems/gems/mysql-        2.9.0/lib/mysql
install: wheel: Invalid argument
*** Error code 67
```

and full failed installation process

```
[user@mydevil]:<~/fblk>$ ruby19 -S gem install mysql
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/bin/rubyruby-19 extconf.rb
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... yes
checking for rb_str_set_len()... yes
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling mysql.c
linking shared-object mysql/mysql_api.so

make install
/usr/bin/install -c -o root -g wheel -m 0755 mysql_api.so /home/user/gems/gems/mysql-        2.9.0/lib/mysql
install: wheel: Invalid argument
*** Error code 67

Stop in /usr/home/user/gems/gems/mysql-2.9.0/ext/mysql_api.


Gem files will remain installed in /home/user/gems/gems/mysql-2.9.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/user/gems/gems/mysql-2.9.0/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

some other info

ruby env

```
 RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.11
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [amd64-freebsd9]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ferski/gems
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/rubyruby-19
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/ferski/gems/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
 - ruby
 - amd64-freebsd-9
- GEM PATHS:
 - /home/ferski/gems
 - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :benchmark => false
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
 - "gemhome" => "/home/ferski/gems"
 - "gempath" => ["/home/ferski/gems", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9"]
- REMOTE SOURCES:
 - http://rubygems.org/
```

can different versions of ruby and rubygems be a problem? 
or no root access?

Comment: @EvgeniyRyzhkov sadly, no access to /etc/group

Answer (score 1):

freebsd related issue
try

```
setenv RB_USER_INSTALL "install -s -m 555"
```

or

```
RB_USER_INSTALL=true gem install mysql
```

Comment: Great, it worked! I used export command, while on my shall there is no setenv command, but nonetheless it worked. Thank you very much for help :)